# Pull data from a hosted database

Tags: java, android

I have a database in go daddy with a table called Users with one entry. I am also working on a android app where its going to have a simple login screen (user / password combo). I created a class that acts as the database adapter, and a login fragment (*sign up* adapter coming soon).

Here is my **Adapter.java** class

```
package com.android.skyfront.dndmobile;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBUserAdapter {
    private static final String LOG = "DEBUG";
    private static String ip = "123.456.789.00";
    private static String port = "0000";
    private static String classs = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
    private static String db = "Foo_DB";
    private static String un = "foo_user_0";
    private static String password = "12345678";

    public DBUserAdapter(Context context)
    public Connection connect() {
        Connection conn = null;
        String ConnURL = null;
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        try {
            Class.forName(classs);
            ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip +":" + port + ";" + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + un + ";password=" + password + ";";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.d(LOG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d(LOG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return conn;
    }

    public void Login(String email, String password ){
        String query = "SELECT Username, Password from [Foo_DB].[Users] where Username = " + email + " and Password = " + password;

        //Dont know what to add here...
    }
}
```

The connection method works. I am getting a successful connection. What I am trying to do next in my **Login()** method, how do I execute my query and check my credentials against with what is in my Users table?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use `HttpURLConnection` or `Retrofit` to call send this query to Database and get response from there.

Comment: Don't do this. Hackers will disassemble your app, get direct access to your database with your user name and password, and do all kinds of nasty things. Instead you should create a server side API

Comment: @Joni What you say makes total sense. But I'm very new to tandroid development. How would I start setting up a server side API?

Comment: if you're on your own and just starting out, it'll be easier to use firebase storage than learn server-side development side by side with android. It takes a team to create a product with custom frontend and backend. But if you want to learn server-side development and use your godaddy hosting, you should learn the PHP programming language (not sure godaddy supports anything else)